# Simulate rolling 2 dice 24 times and calculating the probability of getting a 6 in Python

Tags: python, simulation, probability

I'm trying to simulate Chevalier de Mere's dice bets 1000 times to estimate the probabilities of winning each bet. I simulate the event that
a 6 turns up when rolling a die 4 times, and I get a result similar to what I expected (~0.5). However, when simulating the event of a 6 turning up when rolling two dice 24 times, I get a result higher than expected. I get ~0.6 when I'm expecting ~ 0.49.

Is there a problem with the way I am running the simulation, or is there another explanation? See code:

```
total = 0
for i in range(1000):
    if 6 in randint(1,7,(4)):
        total +=1
print("The probability a 6 turns up when rolling 1 die 4 times is:",total/1000)

total = 0
for i in range(1000):
    for j in range(24):
        if 6 == randint(1,7) and 6 == randint(1,7):
            total +=1
print("The probability a 6 turns up when rolling 2 die 24 times is:",total/1000)
```

Please help! Thanks!

Comment: Can't reproduce. Gives me about 0.49.

Comment: It looks like you've got your own implementation of `randint` in the first case.  It doesn't take 3 parameters.  In the second case please clarify if you want double 6s or *any* 6 when rolling two dice 24 times, because *any* 6 probability is 99.984%.  I assume you really mean rolling two dice 24x and getting a double 6, which is 49.14%.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`random.randint(a,b)` includes the endpoints `a` and `b`, so use `random.randint(1,6)`.

Assuming you meant double 6s in the second case, you are counting double 6s more than once per trial.  Compute all 24 and then check for any instance of double 6s.

Here is working code (Python 3.6):

```
from random import randint

trials = 1000

total = 0
for i in range(trials):
    if 6 in [randint(1,6) for j in range(4)]:
        total +=1
print(f'A 6 appeared when rolling 1 die 4 times {total/trials:.2%} of the time.')

total = 0
for i in range(trials):
    if (6,6) in [(randint(1,6),randint(1,6)) for j in range(24)]:
        total +=1
print(f'Double 6s appeared when rolling 2 dice 24 times {total/trials:.2%} of the time.')
```

Output:

```
A 6 appeared when rolling 1 die 4 times 50.30% of the time.
Double 6s appeared when rolling 2 dice 24 times 48.90% of the time.
```

Answer (score 0):

randint(1,7) might return 7.

Also don't use is to compare ints

And in the first experiment you are missing a loop `for k in range(4)` and have a weird 3rd arg to range. Typo?

Comment: There is no `is` comparison.

Comment: You're right, I saw the in as is in the mistyped line `if 6 in randint(1,7,(4)):
`